# parsing SOAP XML response with php

Tags: php, xml, xpath, soap-client

I have checked multiple examples and the w3Schools tutorial but I can't figure out the structure of the SOAP response. I haven't touch php/xml in more than 10 years so you can consider me a beginner.

Here is a sample of the response I get

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://www.multiprets.net/api">
    <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Table">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="ProductSequence" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ProductCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ProdNameEn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ProdNameFr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ProductTerm" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="UpdDate" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="UpdTime" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="Posted" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="MPH" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="CNT" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <ProductSequence>A1999</ProductSequence>
                <ProductCode>VC</ProductCode>
                <ProdNameEn>3 years variable</ProdNameEn>
                <ProdNameFr>3 ans variable</ProdNameFr>
                <ProductTerm>3</ProductTerm>
                <UpdDate>20140529</UpdDate>
                <UpdTime>134900</UpdTime>
                <Posted>3</Posted>
                <MPH>3</MPH>
                <CNT>1</CNT>
            </Table>
            <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                <ProductSequence>A4000</ProductSequence>
                <ProductCode>VC</ProductCode>
                <ProdNameEn>5 years variable</ProdNameEn>
                <ProdNameFr>5 ans variable</ProdNameFr>
                <ProductTerm>5</ProductTerm>
                <UpdDate>20141021</UpdDate>
                <UpdTime>103100</UpdTime>
                <Posted>3</Posted>
                <MPH>2.3</MPH>
                <CNT>1</CNT>
            </Table>
```

I have tried to get the `<MPH>` tag from `table8` using this code:

```
$client = new soapclient("http://www.multiprets.net/api/ws/services.asmx?wsdl"); 
$objectresult = $client->Recupere_meilleurs_Taux(array('Code_businessID'=> '**LoginString**','trace' => 1)); 
$resultat = simplexml_load_string($objectresult->Recupere_meilleurs_TauxResult->any); 
foreach ($resultat->xpath('//Table[@id='Table8']') as $product){ echo $product->MPH."< br/ >"; }
```

To no avail as it's not returning any result. If I remove the attribute from the xpath and only keep `//Table` I get the `MPH` from all the table, so I am sure it's something with the attribute `@id`

Thank you in advance for your time and for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that your attribute has a namespace, so you need to register the ns with SimpleXML XPath and use it in your XPath query.

This element declares two namespaces for its descendants:

```
<diffgr:diffgram 
    xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
    xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
```

To register those namespaces with SimpleXML, you need to use the function [`registerXPathNamespace`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php). Depending on what other queries you're doing, you might want to register both namespaces. For your query, you need the `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1` (`diffgr`) namespace; register it like so:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($your_xml_here);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('d', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1');
```

Now you can access any element or attribute in the `diffgr` namespace by prefixing it with the letter `d`. Here's an example using the `Table` element with id `Table1`:

```
$tables = $sxe->xpath('//Table[@d:id="Table1"]');
foreach ($tables as $t) {
    echo $t->ProductSequence . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
A1999
```

Comment: Don't I need to declare $sxe with something like `$sxe=new SimpleXMLElement ($resultat);` to get the namespacefrom the XMl?

Comment: Yes -- sorry, I missed that line out of the answer!

Comment: Thank you very much, for those who might be looking for the same thing the `$your_xml_here` in my original code is `$objectresult->Recupere_meilleurs_TauxResult->any`before converting it to an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
retrieve value from this type response 



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <xyzResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <xyzResult>
                    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:element name="Table">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="myCityID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                                                <xs:element name="myCityName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

                                                <xs:element name="myLat" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
                                                <xs:element name="myLon" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:choice>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:schema>
                    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                            <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                                <CityID>1</CityID>
                                <CityName>Ahmedabad</CityName>
                                <Lat>23.045839</Lat>
                                <Lon>72.550578</Lon>
                            </Table>
                            <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                                <CityID>21</CityID>
                                <CityName>Amritsar</CityName>
                                <Lat>31.705603</Lat>
                                <Lon>74.807337</Lon>
                            </Table>
                        </NewDataSet>
                    </diffgr:diffgram>
                </xyzResult>
            </xyzResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

**using this code you can easily get all the Tables data in $title variable and using that you can easily get any specific value easily...**

```
                $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
                $sxe->registerXPathNamespace('d', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1');
                $result = $sxe->xpath("//NewDataSet");
                echo "<pre>";
                //print_r($result[0]);
                foreach ($result[0] as $title) {
                    print_r($title);

                }
```